# Parsing PHP ini File Causes Deprecated Error

Tags: php, deprecated, ini

I am getting a php error by parsing the following command

system.ini file

```
#comment 1 here
product=2
#comment 2 here
items=1
```

I am using

```
$items = parse_ini_file("system.ini", false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

to parse the file.

However, I am getting

```
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated  error.
```

I don't have the access to the `system.ini`. Is there anything I can do in the php file to pass the parsing for the comments? Thanks!

Comment: As you have no access to the ini file; you can suppress that warning with the `@` symbol. `$items = @parse_ini_file("system.ini", false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);`

Comment: Alternatively you could suppress all depreciated warnings with `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);` towards the top of your code.

Comment: @worldofjr These are worth a real answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Answered for real :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have no access to the ini file; you can suppress that warning with the `@` symbol.

```
$items = @parse_ini_file("system.ini", false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

Alternatively you could suppress all depreciated warnings with;

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

towards the top of your code.